# How can I extract png images from plist files?

Tags: png, plist

I currently have a set of plist files. Inside are png images, some files have numerous images. I'm using win64 vista.

I've looked for things specifically for this such as FileJuicer, but that is only for mac users.

Comment: I think plist files are property list files. Do they contain image filenames only, or the actual image data? If the latter, how are they encoded, or what program produced them?

Comment: http://www1.picturepush.com/photo/a/5700734/img/5700734.png
This image is what one of them look like in what I assume is the code view?

Comment: That doesn't contain any pixel data. The actual png files must be somewhere else. BTW plist files can be in XML format, so that could be a screenshot of the raw contents of the plist file that you posted.

Comment: Are you saying there is another way I could view it to show the pixel data?

Comment: No, I'm suggesting that the .png files are stored on disk literally as .png files. Somewhere. I have no idea where.

Comment: The plist will point to images in the Xcode project.  Do the plist files you have actually have substantial size?

Comment: Ok, this looks a bit different and has the names of the png images as well, the screen is just a portion of the full text. Is this any closer to what I'm supposed to be looking for? http://www3.picturepush.com/photo/a/5700816/img/5700816.png

Comment: Most range from 1.14-58.0kb and then there are two that are 638 and 966 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

I have written this script to unpack `png` files in the `plist` file packed by [TexturePacker](http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker/)

First, make sure you have both the png and plist files in the same directory, in my case: freeGifts.plist and freeGifts.png

Second, same the following script as unpack_plist.py

Then, python unpack_plist.py freeGifts, it will generate lots of png files to a directory named freeGifts

Requirement: python, PIL

```
#! /usr/lical/bin/python
import os,Image,sys
from xml.etree import ElementTree

def tree_to_dict(tree):
    d = {}
    for index, item in enumerate(tree):
        if item.tag == 'key':
            if tree[index+1].tag == 'string':
                d[item.text] = tree[index + 1].text
            elif tree[index + 1].tag == 'true':
                d[item.text] = True
            elif tree[index + 1].tag == 'false':
                d[item.text] = False
            elif tree[index+1].tag == 'dict':
                d[item.text] = tree_to_dict(tree[index+1])
    return d

def gen_png_from_plist(plist_filename, png_filename):
    file_path = plist_filename.replace('.plist', '')
    big_image = Image.open(png_filename)
    root = ElementTree.fromstring(open(plist_filename, 'r').read())
    plist_dict = tree_to_dict(root[0])
    to_list = lambda x: x.replace('{','').replace('}','').split(',')
    for k,v in plist_dict['frames'].items():
        rectlist = to_list(v['frame'])
        width = int( rectlist[3] if v['rotated'] else rectlist[2] )
        height = int( rectlist[2] if v['rotated'] else rectlist[3] )
        box=( 
            int(rectlist[0]),
            int(rectlist[1]),
            int(rectlist[0]) + width,
            int(rectlist[1]) + height,
            )
        sizelist = [ int(x) for x in to_list(v['sourceSize'])]
        rect_on_big = big_image.crop(box)
        result_image = Image.new('RGBA', sizelist, (0,0,0,0))
        result_box=(
            ( sizelist[0] - width )/2,
            ( sizelist[1] - height )/2,
            ( sizelist[0] + width )/2,
            ( sizelist[1] + height )/2
            )
        result_image.paste(rect_on_big, result_box, mask=0)
        if v['rotated']:
            result_image = result_image.rotate(90)
        if not os.path.isdir(file_path):
            os.mkdir(file_path)
        outfile = (file_path+'/' + k).replace('gift_', '')
        print outfile, "generated"
        result_image.save(outfile)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    filename = sys.argv[1]
    plist_filename = filename + '.plist'
    png_filename = filename + '.png'
    if (os.path.exists(plist_filename) and os.path.exists(png_filename)):
        gen_png_from_plist( plist_filename, png_filename )
    else:
        print "make sure you have boith plist and png files in the same directory"
```

Answer (score 0):

Lol, this is all Steve Jobs' doing.  You could parse the plist in C# using ChadBurggraf's library https://github.com/ChadBurggraf/plists-cs.  But as discussed in the comments, the files you want probably aren't in the plist file.

Comment: There is also a .dat file in the same directory as the plist files. Would that make more sense? And how would I go by extracting images from it?

Comment: And I should mention the .dat file is 11.3 mb

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Sean.Z.
for the unpack_plist.py, you need:
1: PIL have been installed on you pc.
2: use python 2.5
    `python2.5 unpack_plist.py birdfly`

or you will fail.
-----2013-07-25--
for some plist which is rotated, the above spcript may have some bugs. i modify it like following:

```
#python2.5 unpack_plist.py birdfly 


#! /usr/lical/bin/python
import os,Image,sys
from xml.etree import ElementTree

    def tree_to_dict(tree):
    d = {}
    for index, item in enumerate(tree):
        if item.tag == 'key':
            if tree[index+1].tag == 'string':
                d[item.text] = tree[index + 1].text
            elif tree[index + 1].tag == 'true':
                d[item.text] = True
            elif tree[index + 1].tag == 'false':
                d[item.text] = False
            elif tree[index+1].tag == 'dict':
                d[item.text] = tree_to_dict(tree[index+1])
    return d

    def gen_png_from_plist(plist_filename, png_filename):
    file_path = plist_filename.replace('.plist', '')
    big_image = Image.open(png_filename)
    root = ElementTree.fromstring(open(plist_filename, 'r').read())
    plist_dict = tree_to_dict(root[0])
    to_list = lambda x: x.replace('{','').replace('}','').split(',')
    for k,v in plist_dict['frames'].items():
        print "-----start\n----------"
        rectlist = to_list(v['frame'])
        print rectlist, "--------rectlist"
        width = int( rectlist[3] if v['rotated'] else rectlist[2] )
        height = int( rectlist[2] if v['rotated'] else rectlist[3] )
        print width,height,"----width,height"
        box=( 
            int(rectlist[0]),
            int(rectlist[1]),
            int(rectlist[0]) + width,
            int(rectlist[1]) + height,
            )
        # bos is start & end point
        print box,"-----_box-"
        print v['rotated'], "---rotated"

        sizelist = [ int(x) for x in to_list(v['sourceSize'])]
        rect_on_big = big_image.crop(box)
        '''
        result_image = Image.new('RGBA', sizelist, (0,0,0,0))
        result_box=(
            ( sizelist[0] - width )/2,
            ( sizelist[1] - height )/2,
            ( sizelist[0] + width )/2,
            ( sizelist[1] + height )/2
            )
        result_image.paste(rect_on_big, result_box, mask=0)
        if v['rotated']:
            result_image = result_image.rotate(90)
        if not os.path.isdir(file_path):
            os.mkdir(file_path)
        outfile = (file_path+'/' + k).replace('gift_', '')
        print result_box,"-----result_box-"
        print outfile, "generated"
        # result_image.save(outfile)
        '''

        if v['rotated']:
            rect_on_big = rect_on_big.rotate(90)
        if not os.path.isdir(file_path):
            os.mkdir(file_path)
        outfile = (file_path+'/' + k).replace('gift_', '')

        rect_on_big.save(outfile);

    if __name__ == '__main__':
    filename = sys.argv[1]
    plist_filename = filename + '.plist'
    png_filename = filename + '.png'
    if (os.path.exists(plist_filename) and os.path.exists(png_filename)):
        gen_png_from_plist( plist_filename, png_filename )
    else:
        print "make sure you have boith plist and png files in the same directory"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Sean.Z. first.
But I found that the rotate is not good, and ygweric's patch is not good enough.
because it will fail when the png include jpg file(mode P). and sometime Transparent will became black background.
I try to fix this and my code as below:

```
    #! /usr/lical/bin/python
    import os,Image,sys
    from xml.etree import ElementTree

    def tree_to_dict(tree):
        d = {}
        for index, item in enumerate(tree):
            if item.tag == 'key':
                if tree[index+1].tag == 'string':
                    d[item.text] = tree[index + 1].text
                elif tree[index + 1].tag == 'true':
                    d[item.text] = True
                elif tree[index + 1].tag == 'false':
                    d[item.text] = False
                elif tree[index+1].tag == 'dict':
                    d[item.text] = tree_to_dict(tree[index+1])
        return d

    def gen_png_from_plist(plist_filename, png_filename):
        file_path = plist_filename.replace('.plist', '')
        big_image = Image.open(png_filename)
        root = ElementTree.fromstring(open(plist_filename, 'r').read())
        plist_dict = tree_to_dict(root[0])
        to_list = lambda x: x.replace('{','').replace('}','').split(',')
        for k,v in plist_dict['frames'].items():
            rectlist = to_list(v['frame'])
            width = int( rectlist[3] if v['rotated'] else rectlist[2] )
            height = int( rectlist[2] if v['rotated'] else rectlist[3] )
            box=( 
                int(rectlist[0]),
                int(rectlist[1]),
                int(rectlist[0]) + width,
                int(rectlist[1]) + height,
                )
            sizelist = [ int(x) for x in to_list(v['sourceSize'])]
            rect_on_big = big_image.crop(box)

            if v['rotated']:
                rect_on_big = rect_on_big.rotate(90)

            result_image = Image.new('RGBA', sizelist, (0,0,0,0))
            if v['rotated']:
                result_box=(
                    ( sizelist[0] - height )/2,
                    ( sizelist[1] - width )/2,
                    ( sizelist[0] + height )/2,
                    ( sizelist[1] + width )/2
                    )
            else:
                result_box=(
                    ( sizelist[0] - width )/2,
                    ( sizelist[1] - height )/2,
                    ( sizelist[0] + width )/2,
                    ( sizelist[1] + height )/2
                    )
            result_image.paste(rect_on_big, result_box, mask=0)

            if not os.path.isdir(file_path):
                os.mkdir(file_path)
            outfile = (file_path+'/' + k).replace('gift_', '')
            print outfile, "generated"
            result_image.save(outfile)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        filename = sys.argv[1]
        plist_filename = filename + '.plist'
        png_filename = filename + '.png'
        if (os.path.exists(plist_filename) and os.path.exists(png_filename)):
            gen_png_from_plist( plist_filename, png_filename )
        else:
            print "make sure you have boith plist and png files in the same directory"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have JRE in your PC or you may be install then you can use a tool which i create to unpack .plist file. It also has support .pack file that use in LibGdx projects and .xml file used in many engine like unity to pack texture.

https://github.com/itsabhiaryan/TextureUnPacker